# The test failure message for mockito verify

Tags: mockito

For a parameter class

```
class Criteria {
    private Map params;
    public getMap(){ return params; }
}
```

and a service method accept this criteria

```
class Service{
    public List<Person> query(Criteria criteria){ ... }
}
```

A custom featureMatcher is used to match the criteria key

```
private Matcher<Criteria> hasCriteria(final String key, final Matcher<?> valueMatcher){
    return new FeatureMatcher<Criteria, Object>((Matcher<? super Object>)valueMatcher, key, key){
        @Override protected Object featureValueOf(Criteria actual){
            return actual.getMap().get(key);
        }
    }
}
```

when using mockito to veryify the arguments:

```
verify(Service).query((Criteria) argThat("id", hasCriteria("id", equalTo(new Long(12)))));
```

The error message shows that:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
Service.query(
   id <12L>
);
-> at app.TestTarget.test_id (TestTarget.java:134)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
Service.query(
   app.Criteria@509f5011
);
```

If I use `ArugmentCaptor`,

```
ArgumentCaptor<Criteria> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Criteria.class);
verify(Service).query(argument.capture());
assertThat(argument.getValue(), hasCriteria("id", equalTo(new Long(12))));
```

The message is much better:

```
Expected: id <12L> but id was <2L>
```

How can I get such message, without using `ArgumentCaptor`?

Comment: Side note: `new Long(12)` is inefficient because you skip over the VM's [cache of small integers](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Long.java#547). Prefer `Long.valueOf(12L)` instead, or let Java auto-box for you with `(Long) 12L`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is to adjust the `Criteria` code, if it's under your control, to write a better `toString` method. Otherwise, you may be better off using the `ArgumentCaptor` method.

*Why is it hard to do without ArgumentCaptor?* You know you're expecting one call, but Mockito was designed to handle it even if you have a dozen similar calls to evaluate. Even though you're using the same matcher implementation, with the same helpful [`describeMismatch`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/BaseMatcher.html#describeMismatch%28java.lang.Object,%20org.hamcrest.Description%29) implementation, `assertThat` inherently tries *once* to match where `verify` sees a mismatch and keeps trying to match any other call.

Consider this:

```
// in code:
dependency.call(true, false);
dependency.call(false, true);
dependency.call(false, false);

// in test:
verify(mockDependency).call(
    argThat(is(equalTo(true))),
    argThat(is(equalTo(true))));
```

Here, Mockito wouldn't know which of the calls was supposed to be `call(true, true)`; any of the three might have been it. Instead, it only knows that there was a verification you were expecting that was never satisfied, and that one of three related calls might have been close. In your code with `ArgumentCaptor`, you can use your knowledge that there's only one call, and provide a more-sane error message; for Mockito, the best it can do is to output all the calls it DID receive, and without a helpful `toString` output for your `Criteria`, that's not very helpful at all.